# opengl artifacts using soubroutine

Tags: windows, opengl, glsl, subroutine, amd-processor

I draw my scene using glDrawElements function.
Since I want to achieve situation, where one draw call draws complete scene, 
I need to make shader which switches between "materials" in shader.
I decided to use soubroutine for materials. Here is my fragment shader.

```
#version 440

layout(location = 0) flat in uvec2 inID_ShaderData;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 inPosition;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 inUV;

subroutine void shaderType(void);
subroutine uniform shaderType shaders[2];

uniform sampler2D texture0;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;
layout(location = 1) flat out uint outID;

subroutine(shaderType) void shader_flatColor(void)
{
 outColor = vec4(1,0,0,1);  // test red color
 // outColor = unpackUnorm4x8(inID_ShaderData.y & 0x00ffffff); // this should be here normally
}

subroutine(shaderType) void shader_flatTexture(void)
{
  outColor = vec4(0,0,1,1); // test blue color
//  outColor = texture(texture0, inUV); // this should be here normally
}

void main()

{    
  uint shader = (inID_ShaderData.y >> 24) & 0xff; // extract subroutine index from attributes
  shaders[ shader ](); // call subroutine - not working, makes artifacts

/* calling subroutine this way works ok
  if (shader == 0) shaders[ 0 ]();
  if (shader == 1) shaders[ 1 ]();
*/

outID = inID_ShaderData.x;

if (outID == -1) // this condition never happens
  outColor = texture(texture0, inUV); // needed here to not to optimize out texture0, needed in soubroutine

}
```

Question 1:
When using `shaders [ shader ] ();` then there are pixel artifacts on quads drawn.
When using IFs, then it works OK. Is it driver bug, or am I doing something wrong?
How can this be achieved without IFs, using subroutines ?
(I have Radeon 7850 on Windows 8 64 bit)

Question2:
In second soubroutine I want to use texture. But if I don't use this sampler variable
in main(), then compiler "does not see it" in subroutine and on cpu-side glUniform 
function fails.
Is there some way how to do right? Without compiler cheats, e.g. never happening conditions?

P.S.: Sorry I can not post image with artifacts, but what should be red squares are 
red squares with random blue pixels on some 5% of area mostly in corners. 
Blue squares have red pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply cannot do that. Switching subroutines is not possible on a per-attribute basis. The GLSL spec has this to say about your attempt:

> Subroutine variables may be declared as explicitly-sized arrays, which
>   can be indexed only with dynamically uniform expressions.

Thinking about how GPUs work, this restriction does make total sense. There simply is no separate control flow for every single shader invocation, but only for much larger groups.

When you use the `if` attempt, you are using constant indices, which of course are also dynamically uniform. You of course could try to brach based on your input attribute, but you should be aware that forcing non-uniform control flow that way might totally ruin performance. In the worst case, this will not significantly more efficient than running *all* executing all the subroutine functions all the time, storing the result in some array, and select the final result from that array using your index.

Comment: Speaking about dynamically uniform expressions, I checked this article - https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Example/Dynamically_Uniform_Expression - everything clear. Thanks.